# how to add a date picker to Form in @fluent/react-teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

how do we include a date picker to the Form, I didnt find date picker
is there a way to extend with custom components.

[the component library link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-ui-component-library/tree/main/src/components/Form)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Datepicker](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.51.7/components/datepicker/definition) in Fluent UI. Attaching a code snippet of the same.

```
 import { Datepicker } from '@fluentui/react-northstar'
import React from 'react'

const DatepickerExample = () => <Datepicker />

export default DatepickerExample
```

Comment: it is about the Form from the @fluent/react-teams.
how to include the date picker to the Form

Comment: Above mentioned date picker is a component and can be placed anywhere. Can you please share a screenshot of the form where you want to include date picker?

Comment: i want to include in the Form Component of the @fluent/react-teams.
it is json payload to which i need to include the date picker

Comment: here is the playground for the ui
https://dev-int.teams.microsoft.com/storybook/main/index.html?path=/story/ui-templates-forms--kitchen-sink

Comment: Could you please let us know how you are integrating below code in Fluent UI app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NorZ3.png

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/tab-ui-templates/ts/src this example

Comment: We are setting up this sample and get back to you.

Comment: any updates on the sample?
can we inject any custom component in to it other that nortstar components to the json ?

Comment: We are checking this internally. Will update you.

Comment: We have setup the above sample and added a form along with Datepicker to it. This is the code we have added in the welcome.tsx file. 
          <Form>
        <Form.Input label="First name" name="firstName" required />
        <Datepicker allowManualInput={false} today={new Date(2020, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)} />
        <Form.Checkbox label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions" />
        <Form.Button content="Submit" />
      </Form>
 Attaching a screenshot of the same - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKAUY.png

Please note that form component cannot be added to JSON.

Comment: it is not about adding the [NorthStar Form ]  Form as JSON to @fluent/react-teams,  in @fluent/react-teams  we have a Form which takes json as input it currently accepts only input ,text area, dropdown and checkbox  but not Date Picker. 
the example you seems to be a nortstar Form embedded in Welcom.tsx, my query was about passing an datepicker as a part of the "IFormProps"

Comment: It is not possible to add date picker to a JSON.